# working on tensorflow error-ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 5)'

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,784])

y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,5])

for step in range(1000):

```
x_features, y_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:x_features,y:y_labels})
```

error coming in this line

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you download it is a tensor but these are options:
1: Using Tensorflow without eager mode that you can use dataset

```
##### TF 2.X
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
ds = ds.shuffle(1024).batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
assert isinstance(ds, tf.data.Dataset)ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)

for example in ds.take(1):
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
```

2: Using array and labels you can feed using feeddict as the same

```
##### TF 1.X
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
list_image = []
for image in train_images :
    list_image.append(image)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    print("model load: " + savedir + '\\invader_001')
    train_loss, _ = sess.run(model, feed_dict = 
{train_images:list_image,train_labels:list_label})
```

[CIFAR-100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxpCq.jpg)

Comment: Image array ...